# Setting up network for MSDTC connections: How many open ports?

Tags: sql-server, firewall, msdtc

We have a web server (IIS) and a database server (MS SQL 2005) separated by an application proxy / firewall.  We want to keep the number of open ports between the two machines at a minimum.  Obviously port 1433 (or equivalent) is needed, however, we also need to support MSDTC transactions.  The MS advice [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/250367) suggests port 135 and a range of other ports.

However, there is no guidance regarding the number of ports to keep open.  Is one enough? Do I need ten?  What determines the number of ports we need open.

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306843) are [2 KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/250367) articles that both recommend 15-20 ports being opened in the 5000 range. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596) is another article that recommends a minimum of 100 ports because other applications that use RPC dynamic port allocation will use the ports as well. A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673806/msdtc-how-many-ports-are-needed) question was asked on stack overflow and it looks like that person accepted the minimum 100 answer.

Comment: Thanks! I had searched on StackOverflow but didn't find that question (or the answers).